# Почему игра на pygame замедляется при использовании функции

Tags: python, pygame

Когда использую эту функцию (для отрисовки пришельцев) в игре, она замедляется(игра замедляется в плане fps и дико лагает), при том нагрузка на ядро процессора максимальна
Вот такая вот функция:

```
    def _create_fleet(self):
        alien = Alien(self)
        self.aliens.add(alien)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (2 * alien_width)
        number_aliens_x = available_space_x // (2 * alien_width)
        ship_height = self.ship.rect.height
        available_space_y = (self.settings.screen_height - (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
        number_rows = available_space_y // (2 * alien_height)

        for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
            alien = Alien(self)
            alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
            alien.rect.x = alien.x
            self.aliens.add(alien)

        for row_number in range(number_rows):
            for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
                self._create_alien(alien_number, row_number)
                
    def _create_alien(self, alien_number, row_number):
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
        alien.rect.x = alien.x
        alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
        self.aliens.add(alien)
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать в мир чудных открытий. https://habr.com/ru/companies/vk/articles/201594/